# Shared view in multiple screens

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I´m trying to create a common view on top of the toolbar (kind of a notification) after the login is done. This view only be shown when the network is off.

I have the NavigationView declared in the login view:

```
@main
struct iOSApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           LoginView()           
        }
}

struct LoginView: View {
var body: some View {
       ZStack{
        if !networkActive{
           CommonView()
         }// Try this because i needed the view on top of the toolbar and to be shown in all views
        NavigationView {
          //logic which leads to the MainView after login successfully
          //NavigationLink to MainView
     }
   }
 }
}
struct MainView: View {
  //It has to show the CommonView when network is off

}
struct CommonView: View {
  //Common view

}

class CommonViewViewModel: ObservableObject{
   @Published var isActive = false

   //Other logic

}
```

I need to show the CommonView in all views and when click on it navigate to another screen (all of this after the login is done, not before). Wasn't able to achieve this with the solution above as the view is not inside the NavigationView and can't navigate to another view when tapped.

I also tried to wrap all views in the CommonView like this:

```
struct CommonView<Content>: View where Content: View {

}

struct MainView: View {
  var body: some View {
    CommonView{
      //Main view content
    }

}

}
```

But i don't know if it's the best solution and also the Common view is below the toolbar

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can absolutely use your approach. Here is a working example:

[image]

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = CommonViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("Go to Main",
                                   destination: MainView().environmentObject(vm))
                    Toggle("Network", isOn: $vm.networkActive)
                }
                .padding()
                .navigationTitle("Login")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
            .overlay(
                CommonView()
                    .environmentObject(vm)
                    .opacity(vm.networkActive ? 0 : 1)
            )
    }
}


struct MainView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var vm: CommonViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is MainView").font(.title)
            Toggle("Network", isOn: $vm.networkActive)
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Main View")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}


struct CommonView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Network is down!")
                .padding(8)
                .background(.red)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


class CommonViewViewModel: ObservableObject{
   @Published var networkActive = true
   //Other logic
}
```

Comment: I tried and works perfectly. The problem is that i want to navigate to another view once i tap the CommonView, but being and overlay of the NavigationView and. not inside it it doesn't work. I placed the NavigationLink inside the CommonView